# Quick Conditional Tag Question if elseif

Tags: conditional-tags

I have a meta box checkbox, you click to turn on/show the blow info basically...

These conditionals dont seem to be working for some reason, the first if works, but when i add in any other else if it breaks..

```
<ul>

    <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hm_check_image1', true)) { ?>


    <li>
        stufff stuff other meta info...
    </li>


    <?php elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hm_check_image2', true)) { ?>

    <li>
        stufff stuff other meta info...
    </li>


    <?php elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hm_check_image3', true)) { ?>

    <li>
        stufff stuff other meta info...
    </li>


    <? } else { ?>
<!--no checkbox ticked-->

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

I'm obviously missing something obvious, i prefer doing them like this usually so gives me flexibility to put anything i want between the li tags... not just limited by echo.

Any help would be great, sure its a quick one..

Comment: Please turn on debugging with `defined( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your wp-config.php file. This will avoid a lot of those questions for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a WordPress Question, as you made a basic PHP mistake, but I'll help you anyway ;)

you forgot to close the conditional with an `}` before the `elseif` statements.

This should work:

```
<ul>

    <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hm_check_image1', true)) { ?>


    <li>
        stufff stuff other meta info...
    </li>


    <?php } else if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hm_check_image2', true)) { ?>

    <li>
        stufff stuff other meta info...
    </li>


    <?php } else if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hm_check_image3', true)) { ?>

    <li>
        stufff stuff other meta info...
    </li>


    <? } else { ?>
<!--no checkbox ticked-->

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Thank you though :)